# 18.04.2 Install Freezes After Keyboard Selection

Tags: system-installation, python, ubiquity, budgie

I've attempted several times to install with different USB drives.  ubiquity launches fine and I can select the language and keyboard layout but then the install freezes.

Has anyone else found a workaround for this?  I've been unable to locate a working solution.

Installer debug log:

```
Ubiquity 18.04.14.12
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_ui.py:54: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject, GLib, Atk, Gio

/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:5: PyGIWarning: NM was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('NM', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
from gi.repository import NM, NMA

/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:5: PyGIWarning: NMA was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('NMA', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
from gi.repository import NM, NMA

/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-timezone.py:195: PyGIWarning: TimezoneMap was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('TimezoneMap', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
from gi.repository import TimezoneMap

(process:4650): dconf-WARNING **: 21:01:21.034: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(process:4674): dconf-WARNING **: 21:01:21.111: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

update_release_notes_label()

update_release_notes_label()

Could not translate page (prepare): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-console-setup.py:72: Warning: Source ID 259 was not found when attempting to remove it
GLib.source_remove(self.keyboard_layout_timeout_id)

/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-console-setup.py:74: Warning: Source ID 263 was not found when attempting to remove it
GLib.source_remove(self.keyboard_variant_timeout_id)
```